# Why href="javascript:window.location.href='#xxx';" does't work?

Tags: javascript, html

`href="#xxx" and href="javascript:jumpTo('xxx');"` can work, the method jumpTo is this:

```html
function jumpTo(anchor) {
    window.location.href= '#' + anchor;
}
```

however, `href="javascript:window.location.href='#xxx';"` does't work, I want to know why?

Comment: Yes, use hash, `window.location.hash = 'xxx';`

Comment: Not work yet, and window.location.hash only jump once, I want it jump every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `javascript:` URIs, if the expression results in a *truthy* value, [that value is written out as the sole content of the page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void#JavaScript_URIs).

Since the assignment operator returns the value being assigned, it behaves similar to:

```
<a href="javascript:'#xxx'">Test</a>
```

One option to prevent the output of the value is to add the [`void` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void), which returns `undefined` (a *falsy* value), at the start of the expression:

```
<a href="javascript:void window.location.hash='#xxx';">Test</a>
```

Also, when using `jumpTo()`, the result is the same as using `void`. Since the function doesn't explicitly `return` a value, it results in an `undefined` value by default.

Comment: Thanks, as the example in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void#JavaScript_URIs, href="javascript:void(window.location.href='#xxx');" works fine.